# Missing 'Rollback' button

Tags: support

https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/51696/revisions at the top has no 'Rollback' button/link, only
"Source Edit Link Full". Why is that? Is it because the answer was deleted an hour after that?

The edit was a terrible one because it edited *quoted text* without indicating that fact. It made the quotations into misquotations. So I very much want to undo the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rollback doesn't show on the top edit intentionally. That button selects the edit that you want to rollback *to*.

Comment: Thanks for the concise and (I just tried it) correct answer. Upvoted and accepted.